# How to use the Media Viewer in a WP8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, media

I'm trying to add a media viewer page on my app (very similar to the photo app on WP), so my first idea was to open a new Pivot Page with one photo on each page, but it overload the memory when there is to much photos and I don't have the zoom in / zoom out fonctionnality.

Then I found this cool example provided by Microsoft who do exactly what I wanna do :

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b

The problem is, I've tried many things, but I can't get it to work. Do you have any idea how I could use this cool Media Viewer ? What classes should I import? How to implement it in my project?

Answer (score 1):

The Media Viewer class is indeed not that simple!
I've also started to tweak it so it would fit my purpose, the solution isn't finished, but you can already take a look at it here: https://github.com/Depechie/ImageSliderMediaClass

I changed the class so that it would act as one horizontal image scrolling overview, without the zooming capability.